# File not found error after adding google-maps-sdk-ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using the Xcode 4.6. I always face the problem of file not found error in my Xcode whenever I add framework or wrapper classes from other developers.

This occurred even when adding google-maps-sdk-ios.

```
#import "SDKDemos/Samples/BasicMapViewController.h" // I got error saying given file not found

#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
```

I download the sdk from the below link

[Version 1.6.2](https://dl.google.com/geosdk/GoogleMaps-iOS-1.6.2.zip)

unzip and run the demo application inside the folder named GoogleMapsSDKDemos then the compiler show file missing errors in the file BasicMapViewController.m

**Error:-**

/User/Wrapper classes/GoogleMaps-iOS-1.6.2/GoogleMapsSDKDemos/SDKDemos/Samples/BasicMapViewController.m:5:9: 'SDKDemos/Samples/BasicMapViewController.h' file not found

and below is the screen shot of that error

[image]

I replace that erred line with

```
#import "BasicMapViewController.h"
```

and that error disappeared but showing new error(file not found) like below

**Error**

/user/Wrapper classes/GoogleMaps-iOS-1.6.2/GoogleMapsSDKDemos/SDKDemos/Samples/BasicMapViewController.m:7:9: 'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found

below is the screen shot

[image]

Comment: have you checked the dir samples/BasicMapViewController.h and see if the file exists? Also check it's included in the build files.

Comment: @CW0007007 I fixed this by replacing the line with #import"BasicMapViewController.h" and I got a new error as in the question

Answer (score 2):

This is because of referencing issue.I faced the same issue.A temporary solution is to remove the googlemaps framework and insert again including the googlemaps bundle.It will work flawless then.This happens when you try to run your xcode on different mac simulators or machines

Comment: What is a permenant solution then?